# Does Monaco editor use a shared TypeScript worker across multiple editor instances?

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

I'm using multiple Monaco editor instances in my React application using the `Editor` component from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react package.
I understand that any Monaco editor with TypeScript language has a language server, and you can access its TypeScript worker through Monaco's API. Furthermore, I was wondering if multiple editor instances of Monaco in my application use a shared TypeScript worker, or each have their own worker?